# "So mean to him" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**"Why were you so mean to him?"** 
What is the meaning of this sentence & How to improve my English to understand these kind of sentences?

Comment: It is quite a simple sentence, if you figure out what _mean_ means in this case. _Mean_ has many meanings, but in this case it is an adjective meaning _unkind_ or _cruel_. A way to figure this out is to use a dictionary. The trick is to understand what the function of the word _mean_  is in a given sentence. Here, it cannot be a noun or a verb (we already have a verb in the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is asked after someone has been mean to someone else.
'So' makes subject(mean) worse. Saying 'it tasted so good' makes it sound tastier than 'it tasted good'.
Mean, in this sentence, is an act of being rude to someone, making them feel bad. Like saying something bad about them or hurting them in anyway.

In regards to improving your english, thats a tough one! Practice is key and exposing yourself to writing will help A LOT. If your in a situation where you cant get classes to help improve or tutoring, reading simple magazines will help you understand the basics then overtime moving to newspapers, online articles. Reading in general will help! If you can't understand a lot of the words or what the sentences mean, you should put that book down and read something easier however, if it is challenging it useful to continue to read it in order to improve.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Mean** in this sense means **Rude/Cruel/Blunt/Crude**.